# Can I nest cells in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to nest cells in a jupyter notebook? I would like to be able to collapse and expand sections of a notebook, or cut/paste entire sections.

I'm looking for functionality like that in Mathematica, for example.

Comment: Is this extension what you're after? https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tree/master/nbextensions/usability/collapsible_headings

Comment: Did you see this blog post about the release of jupyter notebook 4.1? http://blog.jupyter.org/2016/01/08/notebook-4-1-release/

Comment: Thanks for these answers! I had *not* seen the new release. Unfortunately, when I install 4.1 (via pip install followed by conda update) the system still launches version 4.0.6. Any idea why?? Also, that extension looks perfect. Unfortunately, it doesn't include installation instructions. How do I install it? Thanks again.

Comment: @ThomasK 404 on tree link

Comment: This is the new version of the same link: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/collapsible_headings